# Create a file with exact name as an existing subfolder?

Tags: windows, filesystems, file-management

I have a folder e.g. `C:\a\` which contains a subfolder `\b\` inside. (So it's like this: `C:\a\b\`)

I want to create a plain text file named `b` (no extension) in `C:\a\` but Windows won't allow that.

So, is there a way I can force create that file?

**Desired result should be**:

```
C:\a\b\    <——  b\ is a folder
C:\a\b     <——  b is a plain text file without extension
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Windows is behaving normally. You need to give files and folders unique names.  So add some qualifier like .TXT to your file.

Comment: @John You are right, and that's why I asked if there's a way to force that. Do you think there's a workaround probably?

Comment: The only workaround is to add a qualifier to the file name .  Like a_  or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. You can't have a directory and a regular file with the same name, just like you can't have two files with the same name.

You can add a non-breaking space at the end of a filename or replace a regular space with it, it will look similar but it's actually different.

Non-breaking space can be entered by holding left <kbd>Alt</kbd> and pressing <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> on the numerical keyboard.